# Восстановление AD после неудачного переименования домена

Tags: active-directory

Добрый день, такая ситуация, пытался переименовать домен на домен контроллере через NETDOM computername, что-то пошло не так, подозреваю, что проблема в том, что я указал в качестве домена имя из одного компонента, без точки. после перезагрузки службы AD не запускаются, захожу только с локального юзера, бэкапов естественно нет, подскажите если ли возможность вернуть AD в рабочее состояния теперь или только сносить роль и делать все с начала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это продакшн и нет бэкапа, то дело гиблое. При описанном выше раскладе AD-организация однозначно скомпрометирована и при дальнейшей эксплуатации непременно будут вылезать всякие фантомы и глюки. AD – капризный каталог и неподготовленных действий не прощает.

В этом случае советую ничего не делать самому, а обратиться в MCS (Microsoft Consulting Services). Они проанализируют состояние дел и, возможно, помогут.

Если речь идёт о каком-нибудь некритичном тест-лабе, то сносим каталог и переустанавливаем роль.

В обоих случаях лично я заново переустановил бы серверы, на которых будет крутиться каталог.

UPD (из личного опыта): когда мне надо сделать что-то с AD, я досконально изучаю Whitepapers по вопросу. До того состояния, что они начинают мне сниться! Потом поднимаю тестовую песочницу и отрабатываю все возможные варианты внедрения. И только потом переношу это в продуктив. Это долгая, нудная, но **единственно правильная** практика.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) каталог новый и не очень большой за пару часов думаю перебью все с начала, раз такое дело. Буду имметь ввиду теперь, что AD настолько капризный.